# ¿Cómo agregar información de 3 listas en otra lista?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa donde le pregunto a un usuario diferentes nombres con sus días de cumpleaños (día y mes) y al final quiero poner en una lista todos los meses (enero a diciembre) con los respectivos cumpleaños con el día y el nombre de quien cumple años. Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
times=int(input("Cuantos nombres? "))


names=[]
day=[]
month=[]
for i in range(0,times):
          names.append(input("Nombre? "))
          day.append(input("dia de cumpleaños? "))
          month.append(input("mes de cumpleaños? "))
```

Lo que hice es crear 3 listas para nombres día y mes pero estoy atascado, no sé como puedo poner los nombres con los días en una lista de todos los meses alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres que quede tu lista final? Si no tienes obligación de usar listas posiblemente sea mejor usar diccionarios (Usando los meses como claves). Algo como  `{"Enero": {"Juan": 14, "Elena": 24}, "Febrero": {"Luís": 27}, ...}`, si vas luego a realizar búsquedas (como listar quien cumple años en un mes determinado) será mucho más simple y eficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy práctica tal como te sugirió @FjSevilla, es la de usar un [diccionario](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Esta estructura es similar a un diccionario físico, dónde tienes un `clave` y un `valor`. Algunas consideraciones de los diccionarios:

- Las `claves` no se pueden repetir
- El acceso por medio de la clave es sumamente eficiente, mucho mejor que buscar los valores en una lista
- `valor` puede ser cualquier tipo de dato, incluso otro diccionario
- Los valores son mutables las claves no

Adaptando un poco tu código:

```
times=int(input("Cuantos nombres? "))

cumples = {}

for i in range(0,times):
    nombre = input("Nombre? ")
    dia = input("dia de cumpleaños? ")
    mes = input("mes de cumpleaños? ")

    lista = cumples.get(mes, [])
    lista.append((nombre,dia))
    cumples[mes] = lista

print(cumples)
```

Explicación:

La idea es salvar en cada "mes" una lista de los cumpleaños (nombre y día).

- En primer lugar, declaramos un diccionario vacío con `cumples = {}`
- Ya en el ciclo, buscamos por la clave `mes` el `valor`, haciendo: `cumples.get(mes, [])`. Esta forma de acceder tiene la particularidad que: sí la clave ya existe, nos retornará el valor asociado, caso contrario nos retornará una lista vacía.
- Con `lista.append((nombre,dia))` lo que hacemos es agregar una `tupla` con el nombre y el día ingresado por el usuario a la lista asociada a la clave `mes`.
- Por último actualizamos el valor de la clave con `cumples[mes] = lista`

Si ejecutamos este código y cargamos dos personas con fecha de cumpleaños en el mismo mes y otra en otro mes, nuestro diccionario será algo así:

```
{'enero': [('juan', '12'), ('pedro', '26')], 'junio': [('natalia','1')]}
```

Si necesitaras acceder al conjunto de todos los cumpleaños y armar una lista más plana, podrías hacer esto:

```
for k, v in cumples.items():
  for t in v:
    print("mes {0}: día: {1} nombre: {2}".format(k, t[1], t[0]))
```

y obtendrías una salida como esta:

```
mes enero: día: 12 nombre: juan
mes enero: día: 26 nombre: pedro
mes junio: día: 1 nombre: natalia
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio demasiado, ya lo probe y nadamas le tengo que acoplarlo bien y estara listo gracias de nuevo